# Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) in an array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management

So i have this function P on program and i used valgrind to test the program and i got this error `Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)` at this line `if (strcmp(nome,v[i].nome) == 0)`, the program works fine but it still gives that error and i dont know why, because everything is initialiezed.

Program:

```
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_CHARS 1024
#define MAX_SIZE 50

typedef struct vit
{
    int id;
    char nome[MAX_CHARS];
    int vit;
} vit;

void P(char nome[],int size,char s[][1024],vit v[])
{
    if (equipa_in(nome,size,s) == 0)
    {
        printf("Equipa inexistente.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<=size;i++)
        {
            if (strcmp(nome,v[i].nome) == 0)
            {
              printf("%s %d\n",v[i].nome,v[i].vit);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
 char set_str[MAX_SIZE][MAX_CHARS];
 strcpy(set_str[0],"fcb");
 vit victories[1];
 victories[0] = {0,"fcb",0};
 P("fcb",1,set_str,victories);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for(i=0;i<=size;i++)` ==> `for (i = 0; i < size; i++)`

Comment: MSVC gives a syntax error for `victories[0] = {0,"fcb",0};`. Perhaps `vit victories[1] = {0,"fcb",0};`

Comment: yeah i just fixed it i forgot to initialize the arrays like i forgot to do `char set_str[MAX_SIZE][MAX_CHARS]; = {0};` and  `vit victories[1]; = {0}`, but thanks